# After 18.04 install, actions formerly requiring two sequential taps ('double-tap") on a trackpad now require three taps

Tags: touchpad

After 18.04 install, actions formerly requiring two sequential taps ('double-tap") on a trackpad now require three taps. One-finger taps in both cases. The trackpad is part of a Logitech wireless keyboard.

```
david@gort:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K400                             id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech K400                             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
david@gort:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Further detail is required. What trackpad are you using? The output of `xinput` might give us some clues. Please [edit] that into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively You could download the "GnomeTweakTool" and tune or deactivate it under Mouse & Keyboard > Click Emulation